# Как удалить пустые строки в конце файла?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Добрый вечер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, код *(php)*, который будет **удалять пустые строки в конце файла.** О чем я? К примеру есть текстовый файл:

```
Строка
-пусто
Строка
-пусто
```

и из него нужно получить:

```
Строка
-пусто
Строка
```

Как такое реализовать *(знаю, что через регулярное выражение, но через какое? Я с составлением регулярок только начал знакомиться).*

Comment: а зачем посредине пустая строка? Или её тоже надо удалять?

Comment: @Эдуард, нет, ее не надо удалять. Я же писал: **код, который будет удалять пустые строки в конце файла**, а не все пустые строки подряд.

Comment: Ну например: прочитать файл с помощью `file_get_contents()`, если два последних символа == `\n\n`, то удалить последний, сохранить в файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [trim](http://www.php.su/trim)

Правда удаляет не только в конце, но и в начале.

```
$str = 'Строка

Строка
';

$str = trim($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

> *код, который будет удалять пустые строки в конце файла*

Читаете файл например в массив; получаете последний элемент массива; проверяете этот элемент на пустоту, и удаляете этот элемент из массива *(если он пуст)*. Ну а далее, если нужно, перезаписываете ваш текст файл. Ниже пример без перезаписи файла:

```
$file = 'file.txt';

$lines = file_exists($file) ? file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) : [];

if (empty(end($lines))) {
    unset($lines[key($lines)]);
}

var_dump($lines);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Строка' (length=12)
  1 => string '' (length=0)
  2 => string 'Строка' (length=12)
```